# Data_Extractor Python Outputting wrong year

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I am trying to complete a fairly simple task - extract the dates from a corpora of emails (all time-stamped). I've tried a few different Python packages, none of which seem to work. Below is

```
from date_extractor import extract_dates

y = "Message-ID: <18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@thyme> Date: Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)"
dates = extract_dates(y)  
for i in dates:
    print i
```

Results in:

```
2010-08-01 00:00:00+00:00
2001-05-14 00:00:00+00:00
1939-01-06 00:00:00+00:00
2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
2007-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

The right time stamp (2001-05-14) is in there, but so are a bunch of other random dates. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you're using assumes all numbers are dates.  If your emails have similar formats, you could help the library by providing only the date segment, something like ::

```
>>> import re
>>> y = "Message-ID: <18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@thyme> Date: Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)"
>>> re.search(r'Date: (\w+), ([^:]*) \d{2}:', y).group(2)
'14 May 2001'
```

You could then pass the `group(2)` to your `extract_dates(y)` function.  If you're using `dateutil` you could do::

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> re.search(r'Date: (\w+), ([^:]*) \d{2}:', y).group(2)
'14 May 2001'
>>> parser.parse(_)
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 14, 0, 0)
>>>
```

I'm not aware of an existing python library that can handle your case without resorting to a bit of pre-parsing.

Answer (score 0):

there are many other numbers in the string that can be considered as date
please try below and see if it helps

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
y = "Message-ID: <18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@thyme> Date: Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)"
d = y.split('Date: ')[1]
ts = parse(d)
print(ts)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work, but I am ideally looking for a package that doesn't need that much specification. Right now I'm using emails, but eventually I will be using text that does not have "Date" prefacing the date / time. Do you think I should just use regex?

Comment: @cgp25 : If you go into the code of date-extractor, date-extractor is trying to extract the date from text on the basis of "date" . Please go to the line 175 in https://github.com/DanielJDufour/date-extractor/blob/master/date_extractor/__init__.py                                                  
    >>> y = "Message-ID:
    <18782981.1075855378110.JavaMail.evans@thyme>"
  Even if there is no date in text,date-extractor will print some date, so my advice don't use it

Comment: @moth It will be changing to a certain degree, but always in typical date formats (01/10/2001, 2 March 1970, etc). I'm not using a complicated NLP time parser because I don't necessarily need implicit time to be extracted, like "yesterday" or "in two weeks".

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, @AjaySingh, appreciate it. any advice on what I could use?

Comment: @cgp25 i think you need to determine the date part of the all string. You can use regex to do that. But i would check it anyway if found date is an actual date or just pattern by using a date utility such as [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)